# An SQL query to update a table field from information from two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: category, old, and new.

Goal: to update book_id from old to new

tables category has a column: book_id

tables old and new both have columns: id and isbn

What I want to achieve:

- take the original book_id from category
- match original book_id with id from old
- take the resulting record's isbn and match it with the isbn in new
- take the resulting record's id and update book_id

Running MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL syntax is a little different that SQL Server or Oracle...](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/cross-table-update/)

```
update category cat
inner join old on cat.book_id = old.id
inner join new on old.isbn = new.isbn
set cat.book_id = new.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you update the category this should do it:

```
update cat 
set book_id = new.id
from category cat
join old on cat.book_id = old.id
join new on old.isbn = new.isbn
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying: You have an error in your SQL syntax near FROM